# PS1 variable in single and double quotes - bashrc

Tags: git, bash, shell, ps1

I've set my `bashrc` file as follows (for [Git Bash](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?q=full%20installer%20official%20git))

```
source ~/git-prompt.sh
source ~/git-completion.bash
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=true
PS1='\[\e[0;37m\]\342\224\214\342\224\200[\[\e[0m\]\[\e[1;32m\]\u\[\e[0;37m\]:\[\e[1;34m\]\h\[\e[0;37m\]]\342\224\200[\[\e[33m\]\W\[\e[0;37m\]]\342\224\200[\[\e[1;33m\]\@\[\e[0m\]]$(__git_ps1)\n\[\e[0;37m\]\342\224\224\342\224\200\342\224\200\[\e[1;36m\]\$\[\e[0m\] '
```

ignoring the octal characters, it shortens down to:

```
PS1='\[\e[0;37m\]-[\[\e[0m\]\[\e[1;32m\]\u\[\e[0;37m\]:\[\e[1;34m\]\h\[\e[0;37m\]]-[\[\e[33m\]\W\[\e[0;37m\]]-[\[\e[1;33m\]\@\[\e[0m\]]$(__git_ps1)\n\[\e[0;37m\]-\[\e[1;36m\]\$\[\e[0m\] '
```

This works just fine, except for when I try to get the command status symbols by using the following segment (as seen on [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt#From_Arch_Forum_.231)):

```
\$([[ \$? != 0 ]] && echo \"[\[\e[1;31m\]X\[\e[0;37m\]]-\") # again, shortened the octal codes for readability
```

The only different I noticed was the usage of double quotes on ArchWiki and single quotes in my case. So, I used double-quotes in my file as well:

```
PS1="\[\e[0;37m\]\$([[ \$? != 0 ]] && echo \"[\[\e[1;31m\]X\[\e[0;37m\]]-\")-[\[\e[0m\]\[\e[1;32m\]\u\[\e[0;37m\]:\[\e[1;34m\]\h\[\e[0;37m\]]-[\[\e[33m\]\W\[\e[0;37m\]]-[\[\e[1;33m\]\@\[\e[0m\]]$(__git_ps1)\n\[\e[0;37m\]-\[\e[1;36m\]\$\[\e[0m\] "
```

and then include the aforementioned segment of code:

```
PS1="\[\e[0;37m\]-[\[\e[0m\]\[\e[1;32m\]\u\[\e[0;37m\]:\[\e[1;34m\]\h\[\e[0;37m\]]-[\[\e[33m\]\W\[\e[0;37m\]]-[\[\e[1;33m\]\@\[\e[0m\]]$(__git_ps1)\n\[\e[0;37m\]-\[\e[1;36m\]\$\[\e[0m\] "
```

This works fine, except that my git-auto-completion no longer functions. If I move into a git repository, the `$(__git_ps1)` returns nothing. If I restart bash from inside a git repo, it displays the current branch but again fails to execute when I leave the directory or switch branch.

Is there a difference in the following statements:

```
x="yzx"
x='yzx'
```

### PS

The environment in Windows 7, in case someone wonders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you have a number of escape characters using `\`.  The difference between `"..."` and `'...'` is that the shell peeks inside the double quotes to interpret escape sequences whereas in the case of single quotes, it takes the backslash literally.  Try the following:

```
echo '\$foo'
echo "\$foo"
```

and you will see the difference.

Comment: specifically, `$(__git_ps1)` is being substituted *when PS1 is defined* due to the double quotes. Instead you want to delay the evaluation until your prompt is displayed, so single quotes would be more appropriate.